# Close slider when scrolling to top before timeout classes start

Tags: jquery, html

Having this issue with this slider. This scroll script works fine when im scrolling slowly. The idea is when the active == 1 (it's checking for a variable in local storage) the slider pops out after 3 seconds. And this works all fine when going slow. Scroll down slowly...it pops up. Scroll back up slowly...it goes away.

The problem is the setTimeout. If I scroll very fast up and down and bring it to the top it adds the class 'isActive' after the timeout because it went 'down' then back 'up' really quick. So you could be scrolling very fast, go to the top, and the slider will pop up after 3100.

Trying to figure out a way to prevent the timeout from firing at all once you get to the point up top.

```js
var tabElement = $('.c-risk-survey-slideout');
var active = 0;


$(window).scroll(function() {
  var cookie1 = getCookie("cookie1");
  var cookie2 = getCookie("cookie2");
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('html').height() / 9) {


    if (cookie1 !== null && cookie2 !== null) {

      if (screen.width > 767) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          if (localStorage.getItem('Survey') == null) {
            tabElement.addClass('isActive');

          }

          if (active == 1) {

            tabElement.addClass('tab-open');
            tabElement.removeClass('animated');
            active = 0;
            setTimeout(function() {
              tabElement.removeClass('tab-open');
              tabElement.addClass('animated');
            }, 3000);
          }
        }, 3100);
      }

    }

  }

  if ($(window).scrollTop() < $('html').height() / 9) {
    tabElement.removeClass('isActive');

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c-risk-survey-slideout d-flex animated bounce">
  <div class="c-risk-survey-slideout__tab d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><i class="c-risk-survey-slideout__caret far fa-angle-left"></i></div>
  <div class="c-risk-survey-slideout__main d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column u-px-8">
    <h3 class="c-risk-survey-slideout__title text-center font-weight-bold text-white u-my-0 u-mb-3">Where are your security gaps?</h3>
    <button class="btn btn--purple c-risk-survey-slideout__cta u-mt-3 irs-survey-start">Take the identity quiz</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are definitely missing some clears for the timeout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout it also seems strange that you have a timeout inside of another timeout, what exactly is supposed to happen with this?

Comment: I feel the code is a lil redundant as well but the first 3100 timeout is to open the slider fully, and then 3000 later is closes it but keeps a lil arrow showing. Sorry I can't show you full code. It's for work. 

Do you have an example of how to use the clear or is it hard to say?
Do you have

Comment: You can post a simplified version of the code to demonstrate the issue which is also the best way to post questions, that way it would much easier for people to play around with the code and solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this code because your given code did not include enough to run it but conceptually i believe this is what you need

```js
var tabElement = $('.c-risk-survey-slideout');
var active = 0;

// declare your timers
var showTimer = null;
var closeTimer = null;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var cookie1 = getCookie("cookie1");
  var cookie2 = getCookie("cookie2");

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('html').height() / 9) {
    // only setup timer if no timer already exist, you don't want to trigger it multiple times
    if (cookie1 && cookie2 && screen.width > 767 && !showTimer) {
      // assign timer for opening
      showTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('Survey') == null) {
          tabElement.addClass('isActive');
        }

        if (active == 1) {
          tabElement.addClass('tab-open');
          tabElement.removeClass('animated');
          active = 0;
        
          // assign timer for closing
          closeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            tabElement.removeClass('tab-open');
            tabElement.addClass('animated');
          }, 3000);
        }
      }, 3100);

    }
  } else {
    // condition no longer is met so we clear your timers so they no longer trigger
    clearTimeout(showTimer);
    clearTimeout(closeTimer);
    showTimer = null;
    closeTimer = null;
    tabElement.removeClass('isActive');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c-risk-survey-slideout d-flex animated bounce">
  <div class="c-risk-survey-slideout__tab d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><i class="c-risk-survey-slideout__caret far fa-angle-left"></i></div>
  <div class="c-risk-survey-slideout__main d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column u-px-8">
    <h3 class="c-risk-survey-slideout__title text-center font-weight-bold text-white u-my-0 u-mb-3">Where are your security gaps?</h3>
    <button class="btn btn--purple c-risk-survey-slideout__cta u-mt-3 irs-survey-start">Take the identity quiz</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's doesn't fully but I appreciate the help without context. Will get there.

Comment: Actually it might be I didn't set the timers to null, I updated the answer with that. Should work